# Getting only one value of single key in android

Tags: android, hashmap

In my android app, I'm trying to get all values of single key using hash map. Below is my code. but I am getting only one value "maharashtra" for key "blr" and not "banglore" (in my code). What am I missing?

```
    HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myMap.put("ind", "india");
    myMap.put("tn", "tamilnadu" + " How");

    myMap.put("blr","bangalore");
     myMap.put("blr","maharashtra");
    Set<Entry<String,String>> set = myMap.entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> me : set) {
        if(me.getKey().equals("blr")){
            System.out.println(me.getValue());

    }

}
```

Comment: this is not a way of doing that, in this you are overriding value in blr , firstly it has bangalore but then it has been changed to maharashtra.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: you can't. As stated here:

```
public V put(K key, V value)
```

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replaced.

Please read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Second: If you are using a Key, Value structure you most likely shouldn't think of ever having duplicate keys, it defeats the purpose of a Key, Value collection.

A simple solution would be to use `HashMap<String, List<String>>` instead of `HashMap<String, String>`. Storing all the values in the `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got solution. Awesom...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class hashmap {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // HashMap<String, List<String> > myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String> >();
      Map<String,List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

        List<String> arr4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr4.add("india");
        arr4.add("tamilnadu");
        arr4.add("tamilnadu");
        arr4.add("tamilnadu");
        arr4.add("tamilnadu");

        myMap.put("tn", arr4);
        Set<Entry<String,List<String>>> set = myMap.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> me : set) {
            if(me.getKey().equals("tn")){
                System.out.println(me.getValue());

        }

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the point of a hashmap is that keys are unique. so you are overwriting `bangalore` with `maharashtra` with `myMap.put("blr","maharashtra");`

Answer (score 0):

the keys are unique. so you are simply just overwriting the first assignment

```
myMap.put("blr","bangalore");
```

with

```
myMap.put("blr","maharashtra");
```

so, use another key!?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use `HashMap<String, List<String>>` instead of `HashMap<String, String>`.
To add element to map :

```
yMap.put("blr", new ArrayList<String>());
yMap.get("blr").add("maharashtra");
```